# how to run program written under linux in visual studio

Tags: c++, linux, compiler-construction, ide, transfer

Hi
I'm trying to compile quite a big linux program on Visual Studio. The source code is here
http://public.fh-wolfenbuettel.de/~hoeppnef/fc.html
I managed to overcome most problem however now I have no idea what to do. I got an error
 Cannot open include file: 'ext/functional': No such file or directory
The problem is, that I can't find this header file, I've searched entire web and I could't find it. Is there any way to run compile this application on visual stuio ?
Or maybe You could recomend me good IDE on Linux (I've been always programming on Windows)
It would be great if IDE on Linux had debugger as convinient as Visual's debugger

Comment: Did you try removing that include and see what errors you get? This will help tell what header you need to include. Note that standard C++ has a header <functional>, but not <ext/functional>.

Comment: this site mentions a utility package. Do have it !

Comment: @Dark Falcom I grepped the source, <functional> is included correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Porting this whole is going to be non-trivial. For a start, there are portions of the code that run system commands using linux syntax. Specifically:

```
if (legend)
    system("awk '/^###/  { if ($3>1) printf(\",\"); printf(\"\\\"-\\\" title \\\"%s\\\" with lines %d\",$2,$3) }' < .gsv-3.tmp >> .gsv-0.tmp");
else
    system("awk '/^###/  { if ($3>1) printf(\",\"); printf(\"\\\"-\\\" notitle with lines %d\",$3) }' < .gsv-3.tmp >> .gsv-0.tmp");
```

That from the gnuplot driver.

I suspect you are not looking for a major porting job and just want to run the code and tweak things. That being the case, the easiest in terms of work until results will be to use it on Linux and get used to gdb. Other options include trying msys/cygwin as these provide a linux-like environment but on Windows. However, unless you really want to start re-writing large chunks of the code, the app won't work whole.

I should add at this point cross platform portability (and I mean cross Unix/NT, not just amongst unices) needs to be designed in very carefully from the start of an application's development.

There are two other suggestions which may take some effort to get working.

- Pull out the pieces you need. This shouldn't be too difficult. Yes, you might need to re-write some of the logic/prune out some linux-only features, but it should be possible.
- Eclipse is a good IDE for Linux that gives you C++ support. I've never tried it in terms of debugging as I tend to stick to gdb but for Java it is very good. Might be worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the Linux IDE request; I've always used Code::Blocks & GDB under Linux and so far no problems at all.

Comment: Thanks for answers guys. I'll try GDB and Codeb::Blocks and let You know if it works for me. If I had troubles I would ask for help :) Thanks again

Comment: Hi, It's me again
I encountered some problems compiling program mentioned above(I use codeblocks). First of all I included all l cpp h and hpp files into project
If I click build and run I get following error in file 

CompareANalysis.hpp

Line with error

   ReadDDLStream<ANALYSIS> *mp_read_alg

Error description
|error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of â€ReadDDLStreamâ€™ with no type|

ReadDDLStrem is a template class which looks like that
http://pastebin.com/GYEY9ADU

I don't know why declaration of variable I mentioned above is forbiden. Could somebody help me with that ?